# How to stop littering your code with Optional IsPresent()?

Tags: java, coding-style, option-type, code-cleanup

So I'm all with using isPresent instead of using == null to check if the object was returned successfully but I feel like I fell into the pit of littering my code with isPresent.

So let's say I have a bunch of different endpoints to either retrieve or update a model. I would love to NOT have a isPresent in the beginning of every one of them checking if this object exist to begin with!

Example:

```
    Optional<Object> myObject = objectRegistry.get(name);
    if (myObject.isPresent()) {
        doSomething();
    } else {
        throw new ObjectNotFoundException(stampName);
    }
```

I'm searching for the best practice to solve this littering, I can imagine one of the solutions would be to have one method that does this check and I call it whenever I want and my other methods calling it will have to throw ObjectNotFoundException

Comment: Are you looking for [`orElseThrow`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElseThrow-java.util.function.Supplier-)?

Comment: Add the throw statement to `objectRegistry.get()` maybe rename it to `objectRegistry.getOrThrow()` and get rid of the `Optional`

Comment: @Sweeper that's not exactly what I'm looking for, in that case I will litter my code with orElseThrow

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I would love to NOT have a isPresent in the beginning of every one of them checking if this object exist to begin with!

The check is needed because you throw an exception if it's absent.

```
// note how this opposite check reduces the nestedness 
// and simplifies the flow
if (!myObject.isPresent()) {
    throw new ObjectNotFoundException(stampName);
}

final Object o = myObject.get();
// carry on with 'o'
```

which, with Java8, would be

```
final Object o = myObject.orElseThrow(() -> new ObjectNotFoundException(stampName));
// carry on with 'o'
```

It would reduce the code to one line, which you can move to [a template method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern).

Comment: `Optional` itself is introduced in Java 8, so the if block shouldn't be necessary (if optional is already available).

Comment: yeah I agree this is much neater

Comment: @bleh10 You just replied to my comment with "that's not exactly what I'm looking for", but you accepted this answer? I am _very_ confused. Doesn't this "litter your code with `orElseThrow`s"?

Comment: @Sweeper I kinda misunderstood you, also seeing it written down changed my perspective, My apologize